# PATH with apache-cassandra-3.11.1:bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, shell

I have added Apache Cassandra bin into bashrc

When I log in into remote server

```
-bash: export: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/piz/apache-cassandra-3.11.1/bin': not a valid identifier
```

I do not understand why do I have this problem.This is the line

```
export PATH = $PATH:$HOME/apache-cassandra-3.11.1/bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the whitespaces around the `=` sign:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/apache-cassandra-3.11.1/bin
```

Bash variable assignment expects the format `name=value`, no spaces allowed.